# Add a new element to a list, and return a reference to that element?

Tags: c++, list, reference, initialization, declaration

How can I add a new element to a list, and get a reference to the element that is created in the list?

```
std::list<My_class> list;
My_class new_obj;
My_class& newly_created_obj_ref = list.add(new_obj); // <-- this won't compile, but it shows what I'm trying to do
```

Comment: The class template std::list has no a member function with the name add.

Comment: Exactly. That's kinda my question.

Comment: Yes, I were. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write

```
My_class& newly_created_obj_ref = ( list.push_back(new_obj), list.back() );
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() 
{
    std::list<int> lst;

    int &rx = (lst.push_back( 10 ), lst.back());

    std::cout << rx << '\n';

    rx = 20;

    std::cout << lst.back() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
10
20
```

Comment: Compile error `invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'My_class&' from an rvalue of type 'void'`

Comment: @gromit190 There was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

```
My_class& newly_created_obj_ref = *list.insert(list.end(), new_obj);
```

`insert` will add an element at the specified position by `list.end()` and then return an iterator to the inserted element, hence you can dereference this iterator to define your reference

an example

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

int main(){


std::list<int> list {2,3,4};
    int& newly_created_obj_ref = *list.insert(list.end(), 5);
    std::cout << newly_created_obj_ref << "\n";
    for(auto & el : list)
        std::cout << el << " ";

}
```

The output is

```
5
2 3 4 5
```

Comment: You need `list.end()` (without `--`) to insert at the end.

Answer (score 2):

**You are facing two issues here:**

1. To add to a list use the function `push_back` because add is not a member of list

```
    myList.push_back(new_obj);
```

2. Get the reference to the object just added to the list. The `back()` function returns a reference to the object at the end of your list, which is now `new_obj`

```
    std::list<My_class> myList;
    My_class new_obj;
    myList.push_back(new_obj);
    My_class& newly_created_obj_ref = myList.back();
```

*I've also changed your variable name to `myList` as there may be confusion between the class `std::list` and your variable name `list`*